# Escape brackets when using SED

Tags: command-line, unix, sed

I would like to replace the value varchar(36) with char(36) in a file by using sed.
I am trying with

```
sed -i ’s/varchar(36)/char(6)/g’ calls_contacts.sql
```

But the command does not execute.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have one `'` missing, and i'm not sure what the second `-i` does. Also you are escaping the `(` but you are not in extended regular expression mode.

Comment: Yeah, apparently copying the command from Evernote to the ssh prompt really messed up the command. It worked simply with sed -i ’s/varchar(36)/char(6)/g’ calls_contacts.sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess what you want to do is:

```
sed -i 's/varchar(36)/char(36)/gi' calls_contacts.sql
```

I corrected 3 things:

- Closed the `'`
- Replaced the second `-i`with `gi`. I suppose you want to ingore case and be global.
- I unescaped the parenthesis `(` as they don't need escaping (must not be escaped) in normal mode.